# Avoiding glob expansion in fgrep string

Tags: shell, grep, wildcards

I'm working on a Busybox distro that lacks the `crontab` command. I want to create a bash script that updates root's crontab file with jobs listed in a text file. I've got most of the script working, except that when I try to use fgrep to look for the job in the cron file, it expands the `*` characters as globs and ruins everything.

```
# Notes: CRONJOBS_LIST is the text file containing new jobs.
#        CRONJOBS_DIR is the directory where the new jobs will be installed.
#        CRONTAB_FILE is /etc/cron/crontabs/[user].

# Find each job in the crontab file. If not found, append it.
while read -r job; do
    if ! fgrep -q "$job" "$CRONTAB_FILE"; then
        # Appending file in loop avoids adding duplicate jobs if any are found in list
        echo "$job" >> "$CRONTAB_FILE"
        echo "Added '$job' to $CRONTAB_FILE"
    else
        echo "'$job' already found in $CRONTAB_FILE"
    fi
# Replace variable references in job list with correct paths
done < <(sed -e "s|\$CRONJOBS_DIR|$CRONJOBS_DIR|" "$CRONJOBS_LIST")
```

Can anyone help me fix the script so a line in `CRONJOBS_LIST` like:

```
2 0 * * * bash $CRONJOBS_DIR/sysbak.sh backup
```

will be grepped without expanding the `*`s as globs?

Comment: Have you tried `set -o noglob` before that section?

Comment: I don't think you should get any globbing since you _have_ nicely quoted all the variables. But I think the condition on the `fgrep` is inverted, `grep` should return a true value if a match is found, so currently you`ll never add anything new but would add every existing line again on every single run...

Comment: The version you posted doesn't expand the `*`. Did you test with a different version?

Comment: You are all absolutely right about this script not expanding the globs and the fgrep providing inverted output. I guess I tested with something different than is shown. I'm sorry for that. I'll fix the script in my OP to fix the fgrep result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do, you want to add the lines in file `$ADD` to file `$TARGET`, but without adding lines that already exist?

I think there might be easier ways than repeated grepping. [`comm`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/comm) can give you the lines that only exist in the first, second, or both of two files, so let's use that:

```
comm -23 <(sort "$ADD") <(sort "$TARGET") > tmp ; cat tmp >> "$TARGET"
```

The argument `-23` means to *not* show lines present only in file 2, and to *not* show lines present in both (3). Inputs have to be sorted, and I'm doing the append through a temporary file just to be on the safe side.

A brute-force solution with `sort` and `uniq` might also work...

```
cat "$ADD" "$TARGET" | sort | uniq > tmp ; mv tmp "$TARGET"
```

This will of course sort the resulting file (and remove any previously-existing duplicate lines).

<sub>(Of course you might want to make a more [unique temporary file name](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ#BashFAQ.2F062.How_do_I_create_a_temporary_file_in_a_secure_manner.3F).)</sub>

---

As for the code as it stands, I think the conditional on the `fgrep` is inverted, since `grep` returns 0 if a match is found, and unlike in most programming environments, zero acts as true in shell scripts. Also  `something | while read ...` should work the same as `while... < <(something)` but might be easier to read.

Comment: Thanks for all the advice. This distro doesn't have `comm`, so that script is out. The cat-sort-uniq script is obvious now that you've shown it. Thanks for providing something so succinct! Your advice on making the input redirection more legible is appreciated, too.